# Help in troubleshooting strange behavior when resuming Vim from background

Tags: bash, shell, job-control, background

### Latest update

I start to think that the problem is not due to Vim in the first place. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/687600/vim-goes-to-background-when-rearranging-window-layout).

### Previous update

I think I've almost tracked it down. The issue seems to be due to either [`command-t`](https://github.com/wincent/command-t) or [`vim-gitgutter`](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter). I suspect it's most likely the latter, so [I've reported there](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter/issues/813).

### Original question

Basically, if I send Vim to background via <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>, then when I hit <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> Vim goes to foreground-and-quickly-back-to-background; if I again press <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, then it successfully goes to forground. And the issue repeats over and over, as you can see in the following GIF:

[image]

It first happened today, and I've not been playing around with `.vimrc`, nor with `.bashrc`, nor other configuration files in general.

Honestly, as far as I know, it could be a Vim thing or a Bash thing.

Plus, I can't give further details for the simple reason that when I open a new session of Vim the problem is absent initally, then it occurs later, but I haven't understood yet what triggers it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior I observed is not due to any of those plugin, but to [a bug in Vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/9586). Maybe using those plugins makes triggering the bug more likely because they alter the layout of the window.

I was made aware of it from [this question on Unix.StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/687600/vim-goes-to-background-when-rearranging-window-layout).